# ReactJS - Ajax in the sub component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am developing a simple website using React + nextJS.

To keep things simple, assume I have 2 drop downs.

```
   Dropdown A (country)
       - Dropdown B (run time options based on the country selection)
```

Dropdown A is on the main page. Dropdown B is a separate component.I have designed my component as shown here.

```
class MySubComponent extents Component{

    state = {
       options: []
    }

    static async getDerivedStateFromProps(props){
        let options = await axios(....);
        console.log(options)
        return {options};        
    }

    render(){
        <div>
           {this.state.options}
        </div>
    }


}
```

The main page includes `MySubComponent` on the main page

```
<MySubComponent loadOptionBfor={dropdownAvalue} />
```

OnChange event of the Dropdown A should reload the Dropdown B. I see the console log statements that I get the options for B get displayed. However before the ajax request completes, `MySubComponent` is rendered without any option.

How to fix this?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` "should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.", and it can only do that synchronously. I think you are better off comparing `this.props` and `prevProps` in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { ... }` instead.

Comment: @Tholle, good idea, please add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getDerivedStateFromProps` "should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing"](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), and it can only do that synchronously.

I think you are better off comparing the current props and the previous props in `componentDidUpdate` instead, and get your new options if the props you want to compare changed.

**Example**

```js
class MySubComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    options: []
  };

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.country !== this.props.country) {
      let response = await axios(/* ... */);
      this.setState({ options: response.data });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        {this.state.options.map(option => (
          <option key={option} value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```